# Oracle regexp to match only digits after certain combination of signs

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string which roughly looks like: 
 *XXXXXXXXX - 1234567 XXXXXXXX*,

 where X can be either digit, string or sign (<,>,. or space).

 I need to extract only these numbers after ' - '. 
I have tried following:

```
select regexp_substr('17.12.12 <XXXXXXXXXX> - 1234567 <XXXXXXXXXX>','(- )[0-9]{1,7}')  from dual
```

I end up with `- 1234567`.
How to I get rid of `'- '`? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just use `substr()` ?

Comment: Position of numbers are not fixed

Comment: Try `select regexp_substr('17.12.12 <XXXXXXXXXX> - 1234567 <XXXXXXXXXX>',' - ([0-9]{1,7})', 1,1,NULL,1)  from dual`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with Oracle 11g.

Place the capturing group around the pattern part you are interested in first. Since you need the digits, wrap the `[0-9]{1,7}` with the capturing parentheses.

Then, pass all the 6 arguments to the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function where the 6th one indicates the number of capturing group you want to extract:

```
select regexp_substr('17.12.12 <XXXXXXXXXX> - 1234567 <XXXXXXXXXX>',' - ([0-9]{1,7})', 1,1,NULL,1) from dual
```

Here, `1,1,NULL,1` means: start looking for a pattern match from Position 1, just for the first match, with no specific regex options, and return the contents of Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

What @Gordon Linoff was trying to say was:

```
select substr(regexp_substr('17.12.12 <XXXXXXXXXX> - 1234567 <XXXXXXXXXX>','(- )[0-9]{1,7}'), 3)  
from dual
```

Substr the remaining "- " off of your result.

Comment: I ended up using sbstr because I had to finish task, but I thought it was a 'work around' and was wondering about proper way to do this :)

Comment: @Cezary I completely agree. I have many multiple substr calls (hammer) will have to do for now when a single regex call (screwdriver) would be best because of time.